# Differences between ng build and ng build --watch

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular8

I have updated my Angular application to Angular 8 and now I want to try "Differential Loading". In the `tsconfig.json` the `target` is set to `es2015`.

Now if I build the application using `ng build`, I get the following output from Angular-CLI:

```
Date: 2019-07-02T15:50:56.861Z
Hash: 33c0be7176e97a0b4271
Time: 35935ms
chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 3.3 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills) 762 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 104 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 30.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es5.js, vendor-es5.js.map (vendor) 4.84 MB [initial] [rendered]

Date: 2019-07-02T15:51:25.559Z
Hash: dbbb4a6cfe77900eb200
Time: 28589ms
chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 2.92 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 378 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 104 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 30.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es2015.js, vendor-es2015.js.map (vendor) 4.74 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

If I build the application using `ng build --watch` (same bundles as `ng serve`), I get this output:

```
Date: 2019-07-02T15:55:06.631Z
Hash: 123299dcdc0cbcb1c386
Time: 36614ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.92 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 375 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 503 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 104 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 30.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.74 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

Why aren't the same bundles generated? I ask this because I don't know what the correct way is to embed those script to the `html`-files.

Comment: *I don't know what the correct way is to embed those script to the html-files.*: the CLI does that for you.

Comment: No, I have a lot of html pages that uses the app with different configurations. These files are not changed by angular-cli.

Comment: Then before going further you should realize that ng build dorect create a production build. ng build --prod does that. And the name of the generated files will be different as soon as you make a change, because they contain the a hash for cache busting.

Comment: I my above example output are no hashes. What do you mean? One difference is for example `main-es5.js` and `main-es2015.js` vs `main.js`. Why `ng build --watch` does not produce also `main-es5.js` and `main-es2015.js`?

Comment: Because you're using `ng build`, a task that is OK for development, but not for production. For production, you would use `ng build --prod`. I said all this in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, Angular 8 brings a new **differential loading** feature. Now, `ng build` is building 2 versions of each JS bundle. A old ES5 syntax, and a new modern ES2015 version (JS module) optimized for recent version of browsers.

**Why 2 versions ?**
Because old browser will ignore ES2015 bundles, and just download and execute "old" ones. (marked as `nomodule`).

You should consider to use `ng serve` in development mode, build will be optimized for that, less files will be generated (no more ES5 + ES2015).
And `ng build --prod` for deployment.

You can read more details in [Angular Official docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading)

Also for anyone who discover this new feature : [Version 8 of Angular — Smaller bundles, CLI APIs, and alignment with the ecosystem](https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27) by Stephen Fluin.

> You may opt-out of this change by setting your target back to es5 in your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
 ...
 "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Yes I know, maybe I was a bit unclear, but I want to know why different bundles are generated.

Because of the *Differential Loading* feature, Angular 8 produces bundles for legacy browsers (ES5 bundles) and modern browsers (ES2015 bundles). 
If those bundles are generated, depends on your settings in `tsconfig.json` (as you mentioned) and the `browserslist` file.
[See details in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#configuring-differential-loading).

Im short, the target property of the `tsconfig.json` defines the upper bound that should be supported (only *es2015* at the moment) and the configuration in the `browserslist` file defines the lower bound. Out of this information and the chosen method to run the code (ng serve / ng build /...) the CLI determines which bundles to create.

In your case for `ng build --watch` it is the same as for `ng serve`, only an ES2015 bundle is produced out of performance reasons and to make debugging easier.

> I don't know what the correct way is to embed those script to the html-files.

As already mentioned, the CLI automatically configures your `index.html`.
For the other files that don't get changed by the Angular CLI, you have to manually add the script tags.

- `<script src="...-es5.js" nomodule></script>`
  This will only be consumed by legacy browsers because of the 'nomodule' attriubte.
- `<script src="...-es2015.js" type="module"></script>`
  This will only be consumed by modern browsers because of the `type="modlue"` attribute

Comment: "In your case for ng build --watch it is the same as for ng serve, only an ES2015 bundle is produced out of performance reasons and to make debugging easier."

How can we change this behavior? I want my watch to output the same files as my non-watch build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clause `--watch` if you need to rebuild the angular code on file changes.

From [documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build):

> `--watch=true|false`   Run build when files change. Default: `false`

Comment: Yes I know, maybe I was a bit unclear, but I want to know why different bundles are generated.